# $C_n(X;G)$ is naturally isomorphic to $C_n(X) \otimes G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, natural-transformations

Let $X$ be a space, and let $G$ be a fixed group. What does "$C_n(X;G)$ is naturally isomorphic to $C_n(X) \otimes G$" means?

I know that these two groups are isomorphic, since the following hold:

1. $C_n(X;G)$ is a direct sum of $G$'s,
2. $C_n(X)$ is a direct sum of $\Bbb Z$'s,
3. $\Bbb Z \otimes G \cong G$,
4. $\otimes$ commutes with $\oplus$.

But what is naturally isomorphic? Is this relevant with the notion "natural transformation"? Should I have to interpret as follows?

Given a continuous map $f:X \to Y$, the induced map $f_{\#} : C_n(X;G) \to C_n(Y;G) $ corresponds to the map $f_{\#} \otimes1_G:C_n(X)\otimes G \to C_n(Y)\otimes G$, under the above isomorphism $C_n(-;G)\cong C_n(-)\otimes G$.

Comment: That statement can mean a bunch of different things, it doesn't specify in what variable they are naturally isomorphic. You described the case where they are naturally isomorphic in $X$ but they can be naturally isomorphic in $G$ aswell. And yes your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @NoelLundström Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my interpretation.  Let us consider a category $\mathcal C= \mathcal T\mathrm{op}\times \mathrm{Ab}$.  We have two functors, $F,F':\mathcal C\to \mathrm{Ab}$ given by $F(X,G)=C_n(x;G)$ and $F'(X,G)=C_n(X)\otimes G$ (in fact, by taking all $n$ at once, we can view these as taking values in chain complexes). The assertion is that there is a natural transformation between these functors, and that this transformation is is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Is it indeed true that there is a natural isomorphism between these two functors?

Comment: @Quadr Yes.  It actually took me a second to think about your question, because I'm used to the definition of $C_n(X,G)$ being $C_n(X)\otimes G$ The details will depend on your specific construction, but I suspect the construction of $C_n(X;G)$ is done with copies of $G$ instead of $\mathbb Z$ in such a way that the maps involved are compatible with the isomorphisms you have listed above.  This follows from the fact that the functor $G\mapsto \mathbb Z\otimes G$ is naturally isomorphic to the identify functor.